# using the addpoly function in a forest plot - metafor package

Tags: r, plot, statistics, label, axes

I would like to add a polygon to a forest plot with the following label:

"I<sup>2</sup> = 92.2%"

wherein the "2" is superscripted and "92.2%" is recalled from an rma object (i.e. `res$I2`).

Here is a made-up example:

```
library(metafor)
data(dat.bcg)
res <- rma(ai=tpos, bi=tneg, ci=cpos, di=cneg, data=dat.bcg, measure="RR", 
           method="REML")
forest(res)
addpoly(res,mlab=*)
```

What should `*` be?

The below does not superscript "2":

```
paste("I2 = ",round(res$I2,1),"%"))
```

The below does not work at all.

```
bquote(I^2==.(round(res$I2,1))*"%")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to turn the result from `bquote()` into an expression:

```
addpoly(res, mlab=as.expression(bquote(I^2==.(round(res$I2,1))*"%")))
```